# Winsock2 select() returns WSAEINVAL (error 10022)

Tags: c++, select, winsock2

I have the given code:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "WSA Initialization failed!" << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
    }

    timeval time;
    time.tv_sec = 1;
    time.tv_usec = 0;
    int retval = select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &time);
    if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It prints `10022`, which means error WSAEINVAL. According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx), I can get this error only if:

> **WSAEINVAL:** The time-out value is not valid, or all three descriptor parameters were null.

However, I have seen a few examples calling select() without any `FD_SET`s. Is it possible somehow? I need to do it in a client-side code to let the program sleep for short periods while it is not connected to the server.

Comment: Well, looks like WinAPI doesn't like it. If you want to sleep for 1 seconds, just use `Sleep`. (although I strongly believe `sleep` has no place in production code)

Comment: Calling `select` with no FD_SETs does work on Unix, but I wouldn't be at all surprised to hear it _doesn't_ work on Winsock.  You could try using Sleep() (not to be confused with sleep()) instead - that takes a time in milliseconds.

Comment: This is so sad. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using the Windows Sleep() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I have seen a few examples calling select() without any
>   FD_SETs.

It will work in most OS's (that aren't Windows).

> Is it possible somehow [under Windows]?

Not directly, but it's easy enough to roll your own wrapper around select() that gives you the behavior you want even under Windows:

```
int proper_select(int largestFileDescriptorValuePlusOne, struct fd_set * readFS, struct fd_set * writeFS, struct fd_set * exceptFS, struct timeVal * timeout)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
   // Note that you *do* need to pass in the correct value 
   // for (largestFileDescriptorValuePlusOne) for this wrapper
   // to work; Windows programmers sometimes just pass in a dummy value, 
   // because the current Windows implementation of select() ignores the 
   // parameter, but that's a portability-killing hack and wrong, 
   // so don't do it!
   if ((largestFileDescriptorValuePlusOne <= 0)&&(timeout != NULL))
   {
      // Windows select() will error out on a timeout-only call, so call Sleep() instead.
      Sleep(((timeout->tv_sec*1000000)+timeout->tv_usec)/1000);
      return 0;
   }
#endif

   // in all other cases we just pass through to the normal select() call
   return select(maxFD, readFS, writeFS, exceptFS, timeout);
}
```

... then just call proper_select() instead of select() and you're golden.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Just one more question: `largestFileDescriptorValuePlusOne` means that I have to pass the size of the largest FD_SET +1 in order to achieve compatibility?

Comment: You have to compute the maximum value of all the socket fd values that you added to any of the fd_set objects (via the FD_SET() macro), and add one to that.

Answer (score 0):

From the notorious and offensive [Winsock 'lame list'](ftp://ftp.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/ms-windows/winsock/lamelist.html):

> Calling select() with three empty FD_SETs and a valid TIMEOUT structure as a sleezy delay function.
>
> Inexcusably lame.

Note the mis-spelling. The document is worth reading, if you can stand it, just to see the incredible depths hubris can attain. In case they've recanted, or discovered that they didn't invent the Sockets API, you could try it with empty FD sets instead of null parameters, but I don't hold out much hope.